# grunt-contrib-jshint warning: path must be a string;

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, jshint

I've been trying to use the jshint grunt module to validate my code, but I always get the following error:

```
Running "jshint" task
[D] Task source: C:\Coursera\03. Intro Angular JS\conFusion\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\tasks\jshint.js

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
[D] Task source: C:\Coursera\03. Intro Angular JS\conFusion\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\tasks\jshint.js
Verifying property jshint.all exists in config...OK
Files: Gruntfile.js, app/scripts/app.js
Options: force=false, reporterOutput=null, jshintrc=".jshintrc", reporter={}
Warning: Path must be a string. Received { toString: [Function], reporter: [Function] } Use --force to continue.
```

the problem is that even using the --verbose and -debug, it doesnt show anything to work on the error, just "path must be a string", i validated the file with JSLint (using brackets) and it works quite well, website also works fine.

what i have done so far.

- Unistalled node.js and node modules 3 times (trying something different everytime).
- tried to limit my grunt task to simply validate a very simple js file, and also doesnt work, it means thats not related to the code or my gruntfile.js.

Comment: Gulp seems to be a better option to build your solution, its easier and faster than Grunt;

Comment: What version of node are you running? I just updated to 6 and I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 25):

I fixed this issue by updating grunt-contrib-jshint from "0.10.0" to "0.12.0".

Comment: This fixed it with node v6.2.2, was 5.7.0

Answer (score 14):

I was still getting the error after updating `node` to `v6.4.0`.

What helped me was [this comment on github](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/2922#issuecomment-219263558) (by Jeff Peck):

> I have found the issue to be when the reporterOutput option is set to
>   null. If you change that option to refer to an empty string, jshint
>   will work as expected:
>
> ```
> options: {
>       jshintrc: '<%= baseDir %>/.jshintrc',
>       reporterOutput: "",
>       ...
> ```

Doing that allowed `grunt jshint` to complete.

**EDIT:**

Well, I did have updated `node`, but not `grunt-contrib-jshint`, as per [Zeid Selimovic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435889/grunt-contrib-jshint-warning-path-must-be-a-string/37205599#37205599). That works and is better than previous workaround

Comment: This helped me. I added `reporterOutput: "",` and my grunt task worked.

Answer (score 10):

I got the issue just after updation of node (v6.9.2). It got resolved after updating grunt-contrib-jshint to the latest version ("1.1.0") by following steps:

npm uninstall grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev

npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev